# echo not echoing in for loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a simple bat script as follows:

```
for %%f in (DW_*.csv) do (
 echo f is.....: %%f
 set nam=%%f
 echo nam is ...: %nam%
)
```

The problem is the variable I am calling nam IS being set, but is NOT being echo'ed properly (it seems like it does NOT actually get set)

Can someone help me?

ps: I already tried enabling delayed expansion, but I still do not get expected results (see red arrow)

[image]

Ok the solution was indeed related to delayed expansion.  Since this appears to be a common issue, I will leave this semi-duplicated post online with the following note: delayed expansion uses this syntax for referencing !variables! not this %syntax%

So this code worked and provides expected results:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (DW_*.csv) do (
 echo f is.....: %%f
 set nam=%%f
 echo nam is ...: !nam!
)
```

[image]

Comment: [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Please search for 'delayed expansion', you should consider enabling it. This is probably the most common issue on this particular part of the site and should not be answered as a result. I would also urge you to delete your question accordingly.

Comment: I had already tried to enable delayed expansion yesterday before I posted.  However, I am likely still missing something, as I did not get expected results.  I  have editing the post to show the code and the output

Comment: Come to find out, it was indeed related to delayed expansion, I simply needed to use !nam! instead of %nam%.  Now I get expected results.  Thank you all for solving this issue.